# Search one doc per user on Cloudant

Tags: lucene, cloudant

I have a database containing multiple docs. Each doc has a field of user_id.
Assuming these docs belong to two users: 1 and 2.
I would like to extract one latest doc only for each user. How should I implement the search index?
I now can get a user's all docs by using: user_id:1
But how can I limit doc number to one for each user in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date property on each doc you could accomplish this as follows:

Create the following index:

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         {"user_id":"desc"},
         {"date_field":"desc"}
      ]
   },
   "type": "json"
}
```

To query for the latest doc for `user_id` == "1" your query would look like this:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "user_id": "1"
   },
   "fields": [
      "_id",
      "user_id",
      "date_field"
   ],
   "sort": [
      { "user_id": "desc" },
      { "date_field": "desc" }
   ],
   "limit":1
}
```

If you are trying to return multiple users in a single query then you would have to do something like this:

1. Add a property called `latest` or similar
2. Add an index on `user_id` and `latest`:

   ```
   {
      "index": {
         "fields": [
            "user_id",
            "latest"
         ]
      },
      "type": "json"
   }
   ```
3. Whenever you add a new document find the document for that `user_id` where `latest` is true:

   ```
   {
      "selector": {
         "user_id": "1",
         "latest" : true
      },
      "fields": [
         "_id",
         "user_id",
         "latest"
      ]
   }
   ```
4. Set `latest` = false on that document
5. Insert the new document with `latest` = true
6. This query will find the latest doc for all users:

   ```
   {
      "selector": {
         "user_id": {"$gt":null},
         "latest" : true
      },
      "fields": [
         "_id",
         "user_id",
         "latest"
      ]
   }
   ```